# Parse and Display ESC/POS file in windows

Tags: printer-control-language, print-spooler-api, escpos, posprinter

I am trying to parse an ESC/POS file which is created by the POS Printer Driver and display it on windows. Unfortunately I couldn't find any parser / renderer for that and I've been researching this for 2 weeks now.

All the existing solutions are build for the other way around, meaning - for creating ESC/POS files but I need the opposite direction which is taking an existing ESC/POS file and display it in my windows application.

Does anyone have an idea how this can be done? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, just find the specs for the language and start coding. If the specs aren't published, then you'll have to reverse engineer the format. But do you really need to display the output from those drivers or can you just display what was printed? If that's what you actually need, it would be a lot easier to parse the input to the print driver than the output because the input is the spool file, which is a variation of the EMF file format and is fully documented by Microsoft.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thanks! Unfortunately, I only have access to the output because I am using a middle-ware to sniff the resulting file between the PC and the Printer (all legit). Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The language is [dead simple](https://mike42.me/blog/what-is-escpos-and-how-do-i-use-it) and [well documented](http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/downloads/escpos.pdf). Of course, there may be extensions for newer printers or other vendors, but in two weeks you could have written a parser.